# How to use basic authentication with httparty in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, httparty

The command line version of 'httparty' with basic authentication works simple and great:

```
httparty -u username:password http://example.com/api/url
```

But now I'm looking for the way I can add the basic auth to a HTTParty.get call from within a Rails app. First of all, for testing purposes, I want to hard code the login credentials in the Controller. Just to make sure it works. But I can't find any documentation or examples how you can pass these along.

A HTTParty.get without credentials works fine:

```
@blah = HTTParty.get("http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json")
```

But I don't see how I can make a variation on this that accepts the *-u username:password* part.

The next challenge for me (am very new to Ruby/Rails) is to get the user credentials from a user form and pass it along dynamically, but most important for me now it to get the hard coded version to work.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

```
auth = {:username => "test", :password => "test"}
@blah = HTTParty.get("http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json", 
                     :basic_auth => auth)
```

Comment: Thanks, works! Did you get this from some kind of HTTParty doc, or is this to be considered 'standard' rails syntax that I need to master ... :-)

Comment: I got it from this example https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/twitter.rb

Comment: And `auth = {username: "test", password: "test"}` works just as nicely with Ruby 1.9.

Comment: @Vasiliy Ermolovich It doesn't work with String basic auth e.g. `auth = "testuser:password"`, how can we make it work this way?

Comment: You can do in this way too: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty/HTTParty%2FClassMethods%3Abasic_auth

Comment: Can we send NTLM auth ?, if, then how?

Answer (score 0):

Two points,

1. If you are hitting Twitter's api, unless I'm mistaken I don't think they allow basic auth anymore :(  So you may want to look into something like [OmniAuth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) for OAuth sign-in. You don't need HTTParty or a sign-in form for this, you link to the Twitter sign-in and the user enters credentials there, then Twitter sends a callback request to your app once authenticated. OmniAuth does most of the work for you, you just pull the info you need out of what it gives you in the callback route.
2. But even so, you will still need the OAuth 'consumer key' and 'consumer secret' which are specific to your application (how Twitter authorizes your application, as distinguished from the user). And you don't want these, nor any auth keys, in your source code.

A typical way of doing this is stick them into a `config/omniauth.yml` file  which is **not** checked in to source control:

```
twitter:
  key: CONSUMER_KEY
  secret: CONSUMER_SECRET
```

And then load them in an initializer `config/initializers/omniauth.rb` :

```
consumers = YAML.load("#{Rails.root}/config/omniauth.yml")

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, consumers['twitter']['key'], consumers['twitter']['secret']
end
```

You could take a similar approach with loading basic auth username/passwords, just stick them in some object that you'll have access to from wherever you make the HTTParty calls.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the additional info. The Twitter url is only for example, since the real API I'm talking to is a private system. It works for me, and hopefully for others that use httparty as REST client. Sorry for the possible confusion!
Your additional info is interesting too, will work with that as soon as I am further in the application.